# Azure-IoT - Raspberry pi3 Forever script exited with code: 7

Tags: node.js, mqtt, forever, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm running a forever script sending data from raspberry pi 3 to azure-iot-hub, using the following,
root@raspberrypi3:~# forever start /home/pi/azure/iam/ble_azure.js

After working for about 1.5 days, I stopped getting messages at auzre-iot-hub, when I checked forever list I got the following:

```
root@raspberrypi3:~# forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script                          forever pid  id logfile                 uptime         
data:    [0] NWgI /usr/bin/nodejs /home/pi/azure/iam/ble_azure.js 8990    3784    /root/.forever/NWgI.log 0:21:17:38.742
```

When I checked the log file I get this error message:

```
/home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/applicationinsights/AutoCollection/Exceptions.js:27
                        throw error;
                        ^
NotConnectedError: mqtt.js returned client disconnecting error
    at translateError (/home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/azure-iot-device-mqtt/lib/mqtt-translate-error.js:25:11)
    at MqttTwinReceiver._handleError (/home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/azure-iot-device-mqtt/lib/mqtt-twin-receiver.js:201:42)
    at /home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/azure-iot-device-mqtt/lib/mqtt-twin-receiver.js:64:18
    at MqttClient._checkDisconnecting (/home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:314:7)
    at MqttClient.subscribe (/home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:423:12)
    at /home/pi/azure/iam/node_modules/azure-iot-device-mqtt/lib/mqtt-twin-receiver.js:62:22
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 7
error: Script restart attempt #34
state has changed poweredOn
started scanning
[IoT hub Client] Connect error: mqtt.js returned premature close error
```

Through the log file, mqtt error keeps happening multiple times and forever handled it successfully, what I can't understand why after 1.5 days, I get this error:

```
**error: Forever detected script exited with code: 7
error: Script restart attempt #34**
```

Also why I keep getting such mqtt error, why it keeps disconnecting?

```
**NotConnectedError: mqtt.js returned client disconnecting error**


Forever --version 
v0.15.3

root@raspberrypi3:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi3 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Client.fromConnectionString` to instantiate the client object the SDK disconnects and reconnects every 45 minutes to renew the shared access signature token. (it doesn't happen with AMQP that uses a different authentication mechanism). It might be that when re-establishing the connection the client hits this "premature close" error that we've been tracking [in this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/issues/73).

There are 2 things that could help limit potential errors linked to disconnecting/reconnecting:

- [Use X509 certificates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device_x509.js) instead of connection strings to authenticate.
- [Create a client object using `Client.fromSharedAccessSignature`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device_with_sas.js) and build a long-lived signature that does not require disconnecting and reconnecting as often.

Last but not least, the next release of the SDK (1.2.0) will include a retry/reconnect logic that is way more robust than what was there before. I'll update the issue to point to it when it is released.

Comment: how shall I get X509 certificate on RPi, using nodejs "JS"? any links

Comment: You can refer [Get started on X.509 CA certificate security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-get-started) to set up X.509 security in your Azure IoT hub.

Comment: you said that **"Client.fromConnectionString"** will make the client to connect/disconnect every 45min, but today I found that my script kept working for 1day and 18 hrs, it's very strange, I didn't change anything, I didn't manage to try your suggestions above yesterday and kept forever running as it's with the old connectionstring, anyway, now I changed my script to use SAS token using **"Client.fromSharedAccessSignature"**, to see if it will connect/disconnect again, and will update you, thanks for your help.